# How to place an XAML usercontrol in a grid

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I have the following main.xaml and usercontrol.

I need to place several times the user control on the 2nd row, 2nd column of the grid, By using visual studio it wont allow to drag and drop the user control, so I suppose I have to do it by code, I just dont know how

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="768" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1366" x:Name="grid" Background="Black">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="3" Grid.Column="1" Background="Red" CornerRadius="30"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtCountry" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontSize="36" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtTime" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="180" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
```

**Usercontrol**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="AlarmPro.TimeOnCity"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AlarmPro"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="150"
    d:DesignWidth="250">

    <Grid Background="Black">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border BorderBrush="#FFDE6A6A" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="#FFDC4646">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16"/>
        </Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="#FFAE4F00">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
        </Border>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
 <my:UserControlName Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" ... />
```

`<my:` in this case is the alias for the CLR namespace the `UserControl` resides in. It is defined at the top of your XAML, inside the `<Window>` or `<UserControl>` tag depending on context.

For example,

```
<Window ... 
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:AssemblyName"
    ...
/>
```

Comment: How do you define which namespace the actual UserControl is in? Is that the `xmlns:local="using:UwpProjectName.Namespace"` definition in the UserControl?

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque yes, that's the `xmlns:my="clr-namespace:AssemblyName"` line

Answer (score 5):

MainPage.Xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="UserControlExample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UserControlExample"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="MainContent" Background="Azure" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">                        
            <local:UserControl1 x:Name="MyHelloWorldUserControl" Grid.Row="1" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>           
</Page>
```

UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="UserControlExample.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UserControlExample"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid Background="Bisque">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="81">
                <TextBlock Text="Your Name is" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="30" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Input" Background="White" Width="225" />
             </StackPanel>
             <Button Content="Click Me" Foreground="Brown" FontSize="30" Click="Button_Click"/>
             <TextBlock x:Name="Output" FontSize="100"/>
         </StackPanel>
     </Grid>
 </UserControl>
```

Comment: Any chance to highlight the relevant namespaces? This isn't really helping.

Answer (score 2):

**MainPage.xaml**, I am binding a login UserControl
by using the **namespace** : xmlns:UC="clr-namespace:Test.Views" , since I have my usercontrol in Folder named "**Views**".

```
<ScrollViewer>
<UC:Login BtnLoginClick="Login_BtnLoginClick"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**Login.cs**

```
public partial class Login : UserControl    {

    public event EventHandler BtnLoginClick;

    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string userName = txtUserName.Text;
        string userPassword = txtUserPassword.Password.Trim();
        if (userName != null && userName != string.Empty && userPassword != null &&       userPassword != string.Empty)
        {
            if (this.BtnLoginClick != null)
            {
                this.BtnLoginClick(this, e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password");
        }
    }
```

}

Finally, dont forgot to use the event handler in MainPage.xaml to capture the button clicked event from Login Usercontrol to do other actions.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<UC:Login BtnLoginClick="Login_BtnLoginClick"/>
```

Here "BtnLoginClick" its an event Handler defined in the Login.xaml[User Control].

Create new event for this "BtnLoginClick" event as i created "Login_BtnLoginClick".

**MainPage.cs**

```
private void Login_BtnLoginClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Messagebox.Show("Event captured successfully");
////Here you can add your stuffs...     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For UWP, in *UserControl.xaml*, find the local namespace `xmlns:local` notation: **`xmlns:local="using:ProjectName.Folder"`** at the top (by convention, C# namespaces are named the same way as the folder that contains them, so *folder* also means *namespace*).

In *MainPage.xaml*, add a reference to this namespace. The reference prefix can be any name desired: for example, *CustomPrefix*, as in **`xmlns:CustomPrefix="using:ProjectName.Folder"`**. Then, anywhere in *MainPage.xaml*, display the control by prefixing its name with `<CustomPrefix:...>`.

**UserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl
   xmlns:local="using:ProjectName.Folder">
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
   xmlns:CustomPrefix="using:ProjectName.Folder">

   <CustomPrefix:UserControl />

</Page>
```

The project needs to be built to discard XAML errors in Visual Studio, otherwise the design view remains blank and the XAML has green squiggles.