# Nested Collections add problems

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to show a class with a list of classes in a WPF datagrid.

I have the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Main.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Height="auto" Width="auto" Name="DaveningTimes" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="3"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander>
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" Margin="8,0,4,0"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle> 
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Alerts}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding AlertTime.time, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="זמן" Width="auto"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="קובץ התראה" MinWidth="300">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBox Text="{Binding AlertProgram, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="False" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="PathToFile"/>
                                            <Button Content="..." Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_browse_alert_program" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DaveningTime}" Header="זמן תפילה" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DaveningName}" Header="סוג תפילה" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding ToAlert}" Header="להתריע?" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind:

```
IList<Davening> prayes;
public ICollectionView prayes_view { get; private set; }


public MainWindow()
{ 
    prayes = getPrayers(getHTMLfromURL()).ToList();
    InitializeComponent();


    prayes_view = new ListCollectionView(prayes.ToList());
    prayes_view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("DaveningName"));
    prayes_view.CollectionChanged += prayes_view_CollectionChanged;
    DaveningTimes.ItemsSource = prayes_view;
}
```

Where `getPrayers(getHTMLfromURL())` gets from the internet the data I'm displaying.

The classes I'm using are described in the following diagram:
[image]

**The problem:**

Adding columns by the user in the data grid that's in the row details adds items, but all values are `null`. Also, the validation doesn't seem to work (no red marker or anything like this)

Answer (score 0):

As a good practice you can try to use sub-elements with XAML to only render that specific piece of information. You should then combine those into the larger object. This scales better for deep structures and the XAML's complexity/nesting is kept at bay. It also has other benefits:

- render only the nested piece in an isolated fashion;
- render the same piece in other nestings;
- abstract the nested type away from the nestee type;
- easier to implement with AJAX some complex GUI paradigms (like "overview, zoom, details-on-demand").

Maybe this can help a bit: [How to place an XAML usercontrol in a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972728/how-to-place-an-xaml-usercontrol-in-a-grid).
Once you cut down the problem it should be far easier to debug it, too.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but that doesn't answer the question. If you can link in a comment to a few articles on the subject...